# Disable Inputs With Specified Class, onClick?

Tags: javascript, forms, radio-button, disabled-input

I have a form (see image link below) that needs to disable a group of hidden inputs when a "no" radio button is clicked and enable them when a "yes" radio button is clicked. There are three different classes and each class has four hidden inputs. Also, I need to do this in Javascript instead of Jquery because for whatever reason my Jquery isn't working properly (probably because of multiple declarations within the wordpress head because of plugins).
http://i59.tinypic.com/ofddk.jpg

The three classes are:

poolHeatingFee, petFee and propertyDamageProtection

...and each class has corresponding yes and no radio buttons that are attached to click events that set and clear the inner HTML of divs that display prices.
I was thinking that maybe I could modify those functions to receive an additional argument, that would be the class name of the inputs and have the inputs enabled/disabled within the respective functions that are...

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
            function clearFee(theNamedFee){
            document.getElementById(theNamedFee).innerHTML = '0.00';
            }

            function showFee(theNamedFee,someFee){
            document.getElementById(theNamedFee).innerHTML = someFee;
            }
            </script>
```

Here is the code for the radios...

```
            <tr class="cart_item">
                <td class="product-name">

                    Preheat Pool?&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="preheatPoolSelect" id="preheatPoolYes" value="yes" onclick='showFee("priceDisplayPoolHeating","8.00")' checked><label for="preheatPoolYes">Yes</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="preheatPoolSelect" id="preheatPoolNo" value="no" onclick='clearFee("priceDisplayPoolHeating")'><label for="preheatPoolNo">No</label>
                </td>
                <td class="product-total">                          
                    $<div id="priceDisplayPoolHeating" class="priceDisplay">8.00</div>                          </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="cart_item">
                <td class="product-name">

                    Have Pet(s)?&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="havePetsSelect" id="havePetsYes" value="yes" onclick='showFee("priceDisplayPetFee","7.00")' checked><label for="havePetsYes">Yes</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="havePetsSelect" id="havePetsNo" value="no" onclick='clearFee("priceDisplayPetFee")'><label for="havePetsNo">No</label>
                </td>
                <td class="product-total">                          
                    $<div id="priceDisplayPetFee" class="priceDisplay">7.00</div>                           </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="cart_item">
                <td class="product-name">

                    Property Damage Protection?&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="propertyDamageProtectionSelect" id="propertyDamageProtectionYes" value="yes" onclick='showFee("priceDisplayPropertyDamageProtection","4.00")' checked><label for="propertyDamageProtectionYes">Yes</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="propertyDamageProtectionSelect" id="propertyDamageProtectionNo" value="no" onclick='clearFee("priceDisplayPropertyDamageProtection")'><label for="propertyDamageProtectionNo">No</label>
                </td>
                <td class="product-total">                          
                    $<div id="priceDisplayPropertyDamageProtection" class="priceDisplay">4.00</div>                         </td>
            </tr>
```

And here is the html from the form...

```
            <form id='paypalCheckout' action='https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' method='post' style="margin-bottom: 10px">

                <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Demo Vacation Home" />
                <input type="hidden" name="item_number_1" value="Demo-Vacation-Home" />
                <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="4" />
                <input type="hidden" name="quantity_1" value="1" />

                <input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="Refundable Damage Deposit" />
                <input type="hidden" name="item_number_2" value="Refundable-Damage-Deposit" />
                <input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="3" />
                <input type="hidden" name="quantity_2" value="1" />

                <input type="hidden" name="item_name_3" value="Cleaning Fee" />
                <input type="hidden" name="item_number_3" value="Cleaning-Fee" />
                <input type="hidden" name="amount_3" value="2" />
                <input type="hidden" name="quantity_3" value="1" />

                <input type="hidden" name="item_name_4" value="12% Reservation Fee" />
                <input type="hidden" name="item_number_4" value="12%-Reservation-Fee" />
                <input type="hidden" name="amount_4" value="0.48" />
                <input type="hidden" name="quantity_4" value="1" />

                <input type="hidden" name="item_name_5" value="8% Tax Rate" />
                <input type="hidden" name="item_number_5" value="8%-Tax-Rate" />
                <input type="hidden" name="amount_5" value="0.32" />
                <input type="hidden" name="quantity_5" value="1" />

                <input type="hidden" name="item_name_6" value="Pool-heating Fee" class="poolHeatingFee"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="item_number_6" value="Pool-heating-Fee" class="poolHeatingFee"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="amount_6" value="8" class="poolHeatingFee"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="quantity_6" value="1" class="poolHeatingFee"/>

                <input type="hidden" name="item_name_7" value="Pet Fee" class="petFee"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="item_number_7" value="Pet-Fee" class="petFee"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="amount_7" value="7" class="petFee"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="quantity_7" value="1" class="petFee"/>

                <input type="hidden" name="item_name_8" value="Property Damage Protection" class="propertyDamageProtection"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="item_number_8" value="Property-Damage-Protection" class="propertyDamageProtection"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="amount_8" value="4" class="propertyDamageProtection"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="quantity_8" value="1" class="propertyDamageProtection"/>


                <input type='hidden' name='business' value='juliocpreciado@gmail.com' />
                <input type='hidden' name='shopping_url' value='http://www.dreamhomevacationrentals.com/cart/' />
                <input type='hidden' name='lc' value='en_US' />
                <input type='hidden' name='cmd' value='_cart' />
                <input type='hidden' name='charset' value='utf-8'>
                <input type='hidden' name='upload' value='1' />
                <input type='hidden' name='no_shipping' value='2' />
                <input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='USD' id='currency_code' />
                <input type='hidden' name='custom' value='|||' />
                <input type='hidden' name='notify_url' value='http://www.dreamhomevacationrentals.com/store/ipn/'>
                <input type='hidden' name='return' value='http://www.dreamhomevacationrentals.com/thank-you/' />
                <input id='PayPalCheckoutButton' type='image' src='https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif' value='Checkout With PayPal' />

            </form>
```

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

```
                <script type="text/javascript">
                function clearFee(theNamedFee,theNamedClass){
                document.getElementById(theNamedFee,theNamedClass).innerHTML = '0.00';

                    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName(theNamedClass);
                    for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
                        elems[i].disabled = true;
                    }
                }

                function showFee(theNamedFee,someFee,theNamedClass){
                document.getElementById(theNamedFee).innerHTML = someFee;

                    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName(theNamedClass);
                    for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
                        elems[i].disabled = false;
                    }

                }
                </script>
```